# How to insert only edited values in table

Tags: mysql, sql, xquery

I have table "nol_voa" with different values and I am importing xml file with values in that table I want to insert in another table "#tmpRcIzm" the "id" values where the field "C_REF" has changed its value.
This is the code, what I wrote, but there is a mistake, it always adds two more "id" values which have not been changed.

```
insert into #tmpRcIzm
    select distinct
        a.id
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_komplekts/nol_voa') with #vc xd 
        join nol_art a on xd.art_cd = a.cd
        left join #tmp t on t.cd = xd.art_cd
        inner join nol_voa v on xd.id_art = v.id_art
    where
        xd.C_REF!=v.C_REF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left join of #tmp, can introduce duplicates, and also the join on nol_art serve no purpose on this SQL. remove those two, and you should elminate your dups.

Comment: I removed those two joins, but the problem still remains.

Comment: So question is, in your XML, where xd.id_art = you nol_voa.id_art, is there a chance where your XML have multiple rows of id_art and some row has changed C_REF and some do not?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, I had multiple xd.id_art in my xml, but with diferent C_REF values. Thanks.